# How to show the integral equality $\int_0^1J_0\left(a\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\cos(bx) dx = \frac{\sin\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$.

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I have a rather simple integral equality

> $$
> \int_{0}^1 dx~J_{0}\left(a\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\cos(bx)
> =
> \frac{\sin\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},
> $$
>   where $J_0$ is a Bessel function, $a>0$ and $b$ is real.

How can I derive this, and show it holds?

How about if I add $e^{c x^2}$ to the integrand
$$ \int_{0}^1 dx~J_{0}\left(a\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\cos(bx) e^{c x^2} ~?$$

**Edit I**

One solution to the first part was proposed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1292956/338369). 
Unfortunately, this form was not very telling how to extend it for the second integral.

Comment: [1]: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html Take a look at formula 79

Comment: Using this I can get something like $\int_{-1}^1 dx ~e^{i x b + i  \cos \theta a \sqrt{1-x^2} } $, but how does this help me to get the rhs.?

Comment: So, I understand that the link proves the first equality. But unfortunately, this type of derivation doesn't help me much with the second case when I add $e^{c x^2}$.